# Display div only if exists other posts with same custom field value

Tags: php, wordpress, custom-fields

I've got a wordpress theme with a set of custom fields.
One of these is named "author".

On single.php I've got a div which show the other posts with the same custom field value.

I would like to display this div only if exists other posts with the same custom field value, else I would like to display nothing.

Thanks for your help!!

This is my actual code:

```
<?php 

                        $myquery = array(
                        'meta_key' => 'autore',
                        'meta_value' => $autore,
                        'showposts' => 2,
                        'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
                        );

                        if ( $myquery->have_posts() ) : ?>

                        <div class="related">

                        <h3>Altre di <?php the_field('autore'); ?></h3>

                        <ul>

                        <?php while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post(); ?>

                                <?php        
                                echo '<li>'; ?>

                                <?php
                                $fotorel = get_field('foto_homepage');
                                list($width, $height) = getimagesize("$fotorel");
                                $relheight = $height / 2;
                                ?>

                                <div class="related-foto" style="background:url(<?php the_field('foto_homepage'); ?>) no-repeat center center; height:<?php echo $relheight.'px' ?>"></div>
                                <a href="<?php the_permalink() ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a>


                               <?php echo '</li>';?>

                               <?php endwhile; ?>

                              <?php else : // What to do if there are no posts from that author

                              endif;?>

                                        </ul>

        </div>



                        <?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here an example:

http://codex.wordpress.org/Displaying_Posts_Using_a_Custom_Select_Query

Using the condition `<?php if ($pageposts): ?>` you can print your div or not.

Comment: I've tried to add the condition but doesn't work.
Now my div is not visible… I would like to display my div only if exists other posts with the same value of the current for the custom field "AUTHOR".

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure how you are querying for the posts in the custom fields but the $wp_query has built in conditionals for handling queries that don't return posts.

#### Updated code sample:

```
$args = array(
         'meta_key' => 'autore',
         'meta_value' => $autore,
         'showposts' => 2,
         'post__not_in' => array($post->ID)
        );
 $your_query = new WP_Query( $args );


if ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : ?>

  <div id="your-div">

while ( $your_query->have_posts() ) : $your_query->the_post();

// Do stuff 

endwhile;

  else : // What to do if there are no posts from that author

endif;
```

Comment: I've used your answer, you can see the code in my question.
Now i get this error:
Fatal error: Call to a member function have_posts() on a non-object